# Is it possible to deploy Spark worker without Cassandra with DataStax

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, datastax

Currently, we have a project running 3 Spark nodes. We want to scale out Spark workers. However, it is very expensive in terms of CPU/memory usage to have each spark node running on top of a Cassandra node. My question is that is it possible to deploy Spark workers with DataStax without Cassandra?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would typically deploy a Spark-worker on each Cassandra nodes to favor data-locality (the spark-worker will hit it's local node in priority, when possible).
However, if you really want to decouple the spark service from the cassandra service, you have a few options:

1. Ask DSE support directly, if you have a subscription of course.
2. Deploy a new spark-worker on a new node, and configure it to connect to your existing spark-master. Essentially, start spark-slave.sh . If correctly done, this should work. There will be some integration issues with DSE of course, you will need to try and see. You will have to manage your firewall rules, dns resolution etc... and of course, you will have to configure manually the number of CPU and RAM to allocate to this new node.
3. Completly decouple apache-spark from DSE => use only Cassandra-DSE, and install Apache Spark on each of your 3 Cassandra nodes + an additional node. That would work for sure, but there is some work involved, including configuring yourself the spark-master, handling HA if that's a requirement, splitting correctly the RAM allocation between DSE and Apache Spark. There are hips of Cassandra consulting company that can help you if needed, instaclustr is just one of them.

Good luck!